# Error when creating directive: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi, I am a angular newbie. I'm trying to declare a custom directive. But i'm getting the console error as follows. 

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  directives.js:5 (anonymous function)`

See here : [Link](http://oi61.tinypic.com/2hi3ucw.jpg)


**app.js**

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.widgets','myApp.directives']);
app.run(['$route', '$window', '$rootScope', function($route, $window, $rootScope) {
  $route.when('/login', {template: 'partials/login.html', controller: loginCtrl});
  $route.when('/home', {template: 'partials/home.html', controller: homeCtrl});
  $route.otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});

  var self = this;

$rootScope.$on('$afterRouteChange', function(){
  $window.scrollTo(0,0);
  });
}]);
```

**directives.js**

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', [])
.directive('hello', function() {
   return {
    template : '<div style="position: relative"><img id="map" src="http://www.lonelyplanet.com/maps/asia/india/map_of_india.jpg"  /><img id="marker" src="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png" style="display: none; position: absolute;" /></div>'
    }
};
});
```

Comment: you should declare route inside config using $routeProvider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed Lots of thing in your app, few are below.

1. Add `ngRoute` module inside dependency and `angular-route.js` file in reference.
2. You route configuration should be inside angular config block and It should use `$routeProvider` instead of only `$route`
3. Controller name inside `$routeProvider.when` should be wrap in single quote `'`
4. app.run will contain the `$rootScope.$on` event
5. And your directive contains extra closing curly brace `}`

**App.js**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp.directives', []);
angular.module('myApp.filters', []);
angular.module('myApp.services', []);
angular.module('myApp.widgets', []);
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.widgets', 'myApp.directives']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$window', '$rootScope', function($route, $window, $rootScope) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/login', {
        template: 'partials/login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl'
    })
    .when('/home', {
        template: 'partials/home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/login'
    });
}]);

app.run(['$window', '$rootScope', function($window, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$afterRouteChange', function() {
        $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
}]);
```

**Directive.js**

```
angular.module('myApp.directives')
.directive('hello', function() {
  return {
    template: '<div style="position: relative"><img id="map" src="http://www.lonelyplanet.com/maps/asia/india/map_of_india.jpg"  /><img id="marker" src="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png" style="display: none; position: absolute;" /></div>'
  }
});
```

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've got one too many curly braces in your directive file:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', [])
    .directive('hello', function() {
        return {
            template : '<div style="position: relative"><img id="map" src="http://www.lonelyplanet.com/maps/asia/india/map_of_india.jpg"  /><img id="marker" src="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png" style="display: none; position: absolute;" /></div>'
        };
    });
```